# How do I optimize the solr indexing using mysql

Tags: java, php, mysql, solr

I am using Mysql for indexing data to SOLR. Earlier the data was less, so the indexing happened quickly without any lag. Now my data contains almost 3 million rows and the mysql query always times out and because of that SOLR can't index the data accordingly.Is there any way to index SOLR fastly using mysql or can do any tweaking in SOLR? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using [incremental / delta indexing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Using_delta-import_command), you should start doing that instead. That way only the rows that have changed since the last index ran will be indexed again, allowing you to lessen the impact and the amount of rows from MySQL.

In addition the JDBCDataSource (which I guess you're using) [supports the `batchSize` parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Configuring_JdbcDataSource), which tells the JDBC driver to limit the amount of documents in each query - and issue more than one query instead.

You should also take care to have usable indexes on your data if you're performing any sort of filtering on the SQL content when retrieving it (such as for a delta import).

Comment: I am using the delta importer with the last_update timestamp also. I fetches all data that has got changed before 30 min or something.But that query is also taking timeout.This is mainly because i have like 15 tables doing left joins in the mysql delta import query. So Is there anything I can do it by batches???

Comment: There are at least two options: Use the MySQL explain feature to see why your query is taking so much time, and optimize it to return as little as possible with as few lookups as possible. If you're doing delta imports and see three million changed rows for each import - do the imports more often if that's an issue. Add proper indexes. Another option is to use multiple levels of entities in your DIH configuration, so that Solr can do the joins in the code itself (and cache each lookup as needed). It might help, it might not. Try.